# I'm programming a php system to load an image depending on the parameters given to the method. The image is loading as a broken image

Tags: php, loading, broken-image

I'm programming a php system to load an image depending on the parameters given to the method. This code was working fine until recently, when I modified it. It's one of those classic "It was working, but now, all of the sudden, it's not" cases. I can't figure out what I did to mess it up, that is if I did anything to mess it up.

```
public function image($parameters) {

    //default values for parameters
    $param1 = ' ';
    $param2 = ' ';

    if(!empty($parameters)) {

        foreach($parameters as $key => $value){

            if(!empty($parameters[$key+1])) {

                $value = $value . '/';

            }

            switch($key) {

                case 2:
                    $param1 = $value;
                break;
                case 3:
                    $param2 = $value;
                break;

            }
        }

    }

    $dir = '/resources/images/';
    $file = VIEWDIR . $dir . $param1 . $param2;
    echo $file;
    if(file_exists($file)) {

        $file = file_get_contents($file);
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        echo $file;

    }

}
```

The code above results in the following HTML

Comment: why are you echoing file before the exists line?

Comment: @KaiQing most likely a debug statement to make sure the path is 'correct'

Comment: And also, please define "not working", that tells us nothing.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: Just pointing it out that he posted it this way. he will get a lot of comments about that. @user - have you viewed source to show what is being displayed? Maybe posting that will help clear this up.

Comment: What is `VIEWDIR`? If it's a variable, it's not declared properly. Nor is it declared at all.

Comment: It's a constant and it was declared outside of the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't echo $file before you set the header as that will break the output.

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

"Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file. "